# What is the product of magnitudes $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $x$?

Tags: notation

I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\space (x)=1$, here I am not talking about it. Consider:
$$(\widehat{e}_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}).(\widehat{e}_x x)=(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})\space(x)\cos0=(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})\space(x)$$

Before knowing the final answer lets have some basic knowledge. According to ordinary multiplication, $\color{blue}{(A)(B)=C \implies A=\frac{C}{B}}$ .

Final answer:

In solving dot product we need to multiply the magnitudes of the vectors, the same we are doing here, the "multiplication" of the magnitudes $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and x, but in the name of multiplication, differentiation is done! Is what is done here (differentiation) really multiplication?

$$\color{red}{(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})\space(x)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1}$$

If it (differentiation) is multiplication, is the ordinary multiplication condition satisfied in the above answer, i.e is $\color{blue}{\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\frac{1}{x}}$? As I understand it is not satisfied, what do you all say? It seems some new multiplication rule has been introduced here.

Comment: What you have here is overloaded symbols.  The () symbol is used for both multiplication and for the input of an operator.  The partial differential operator is just that, an operator....so you don't have multiplication going on, and thus no such division

Comment: @Alan: You are supposed to do multiplication not to input anything to the operator.

Comment: @Ant: Yes, I agree with you. How does that answer my question?

Comment: -1 for skipping the comments that help you and only replying to the ones that confuse you.

Comment: @Ant: It doesn't mean anything as I know. Yes it is meaningless. All these things doesn't oppose my argument in the question.

Comment: @AAA: Thank you for the comment. Can you say which comment I have skipped?

Comment: @Ant: Thank you for the involvement. I will for sure edit my question, if said, where the confusion in understanding going on. I really want to get this bothering thing out of my head.

Comment: Don't want to be rude. But how is it you doing vector calculus without understanding in straight forward calculus? Or is the vector part confusing? :/.

Comment: @Chinny84: I am learning these all things (mathematical methods) in some other place other than college, specially meant for undergraduate student, to develop them for research at the early age. Sorry, I am not expert in calculus and vector part. I will learn if you can show the road to solving this problem for me.

Comment: I take it back then. But I do think you should try to start from non vector calculus and take it forward from there, because it could be a tricky road if you are trying to understand the more complicated topics without the prior knowledge to support you in your quest..good luck

Comment: @Chinny84: Surely, I will understand, if you can answer the question I posed for Alan's comment above.

Comment: @Chinny84: I think I didn't make the question clear, I have edited it. Can you make some comment now?

Comment: That's not a real dot product in the usual sense. It's actually just a notational convention.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Are you saying we are not performing dot product?

Comment: @Ant: I think my previous question was not clear, I have edited it. You clean up the unwanted comments.

Comment: @Godparticle Yes. Especially because $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ isn't a number and $\hat e_x\frac\partial{\partial x}$ isn't a vector.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Yes, I agree with you. But, if we can't multiply those things, we shouldn't even differentiate, isn't it?

Comment: @Godparticle It's a notational convention, I think. Because it's so similar to the dot product, we use the same symbol, "$\cdot$".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18866/discussion-between-godparticle-and-columbus8myhw).

Answer (score 9):

Does $\sin \frac \pi 2 = 1$ imply $\sin = \frac 2 \pi$ ?

Comment: Does not work if $|\pi|<2$

Comment: @Umberto P.: Thank you for the answer. I can't say anything for this w.r.t the development of understanding of the problem. Can you make some more argument?

Comment: @Godparticle I can't really improve on Alan's comment above.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Did you see the comment below Alan's comment? If possible can you answer it? Thank you.

Comment: Hahaha, good one... But I'd post it as a comment (if it hadn't been for the upvotes).

Comment: No answer for my previous comment yet...

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Please say what you understand, keeping quite will not solve the problem. I will also be explicit on what I understand. Please answer my comment which has question above. Waiting...

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

$(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})(x)$ is ***NOT*** multiplication of $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ by $x$.  It is the application of the partial derivative operator $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ to the function $x$.  The partial derivative operator takes in one function, in your case $x$, and produces another function, in your case the constant function $1$.

Talking about multiplication of partial derivative operator by a function makes as much sense here as talking about changing the tires on a horse.

Perhaps it is the notation that is misleading you.  $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ is not $\partial\div(\partial\times x)$ any more than the $\sin$ function is the product of $s,i,n,$.  It's just notation for the partial derivative operator with respect to $x$.  In some cases when we are working with partial derivatives, it looks like we are working with fractions, but we are not.  It only looks that way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. Then 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}.
\end{equation}
This is the derivation of $f$ in the direction $x$. If $f(x,y)=x$ then we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x+h-x}{h}=1
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you didn't understand the question or I didn't understand you. I know that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$, the question is by which multiplication rule we got $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ in my question.

Comment: @Godparticle Not multiplication. It's _application_ of an operator.

Comment: In the problem I have given in the question, we are supposed to do multiplication. Isn't it?

Comment: it is not a multiplication. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is an operator. But the value of the operator at $x$ is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}$ can be seen as ratio of differential of $x$ to differential of $x$ so it is 1. But $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ is not a multiplication. It is derivation operator.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is an operator. Yes, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not the multiplication. We have this multiplication: $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})\space(x)$, what is the answer for this multiplication operation?

Comment: Define an operator $T$ from spaces of functions which have continuous partial derivatives to spaces of continuous functions as follows: \begin{equation} T(f)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\end{equation}. If you use $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ sign for this operator you get $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x)$ means the value of the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ at the point $x$.

Comment: @MBYagbasan: Thank you for your time. I understand all those things, as I know. Ok, lets make it clear. While solving dot product, we need to multiply magnitudes of respective operands, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake is that we imagine $\hat e_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as an ordinary vector. Well, it isn't.

We can't write $(\widehat{e}_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}).(\widehat{e}_x x)$ as the product of the magnitudes of $(\widehat{e}_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$ and $(\widehat{e}_x x)$ and the cosine of their angle. But we must firstly calculate how partial derivative acts on $(\widehat{e}_x x)$. After we found it, we have two vectors and dot product is applicable.

Comment: "*We can't write (eˆx∂∂x).(eˆxx) as the product of the magnitudes of (eˆx∂∂x) and (eˆxx) and the cosine of their angle*". Aren't we performing dot product operation?

Comment: @Godparticle Yes we are. But what I'm saying is that you don't only deal with magnitudes and an angle.

Comment: +1 If we are performing dot product, we should multiply the so called magnitudes (though we don't agree one of them as magnitude), isn't it?

Comment: @Godparticle Let me ask you something: Could you draw a vector whose magnitude is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Please answer my previous question before proceeding.

Comment: That's the answer. You can talk about magnitude of the vector, if that vector can be exist solely. How can you assign a magnitude to $\vec\nabla$ when it doesn't exist separately and always has a partner!

Comment: You are welcome to the discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18866/discussion-between-godparticle-and-columbus8myhw